# How to correctly build NestJS app for production with node_modules dependencies in bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, nestjs

After `nest build` or `nest build --webpack` dist folder does not contain all required modules and I got `Error: Cannot find module '@nestjs/core'` when trying to run `node main.js`.

I could not find any clear instructions on https://docs.nestjs.com/ on how to correctly build app for production, so maybe I missed something?

Comment: Are you trying to deploy the artifact/dist folder directly? You should note that some libraries have machine specific code and have to be built on the target machine, e.g. bcrypt. When I deploy my production application I run `nest build` on the target server (after `npm install`).

Comment: The problem is the absent of code, machine specific or not. You'll get the same error even with simple app generated by `nest new my_project` if you'll move resulting `dist` to other location on the same machine for example.

Comment: `node_modules` is not bundled, no. This should be possible with webpack though. I assume you want to remove the source code and only keep the dist folder, right? Why?

Comment: Strange question. Why people build "binaries"? To minimize dependencies, size, number of files to deploy. What's the profit of building then if need the same complex environment as for just `nest start`?

Comment: Usually, reducing file size is more of an issue for client side applications; saving storage capacity (of the order of kB) is mostly not very relevant on server side. However, (re)-starting a built application is much quicker than first transpiling the TypeScript files on every startup, that's why you still built it. If you have set the node environment to `production` (or call `npm install --production`) no unnecessary dependenies will be installed.

Comment: Server app requirements can wary a lot. For someone the (re)starting time does not matter at all, but thousands of files does. So summarizing, nest-cli could not build some kind of a bundle (or small amount of bundles) like for example angular does, right?

Comment: Out of the box, not that I know of. But I've seen webpack configurations that bundle the `node_modules` folder. Maybe you'll find an example that works with nest right away. This thread seems to be an interesting lead: https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706#issuecomment-474514484

Comment: This seems to be an example of a nest application including dependencies in the bundle: https://github.com/ZenSoftware/bundled-nest

Comment: Ok, thank you! Can you format it as a short answer so I can accept it. May be this will save some time for others...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Out of the box, nest cli does not support including the `node_modules` dependencies into the `dist` bundle.

---

However, there are some community examples of custom webpack configs that include the dependencies in the bundle, e.g. [bundled-nest](https://github.com/ZenSoftware/bundled-nest). As described in [this issue](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/1706#issuecomment-474514484), it is necessary to include the `webpack.IgnorePlugin` to whitelist unused dynamic libraries.

Answer (score 6):

[`bundle-nest`](https://github.com/ZenSoftware/bundled-nest) has been archived/discontinued:

> We've concluded that it is not recommended to bundle NestJS, or actually, NodeJS web servers in general. This is archived for historical reference during the period of time when the community was attempting to tree-shake, and bundle NestJS apps. Refer to @kamilmysliwiec comment for details:
>
> In many real-world scenarios (depending on what libraries are being used), you should not bundle Node.js applications (not only NestJS applications) with all dependencies (external packages located in the node_modules folder). Although this may make your docker images smaller (due to tree-shaking), somewhat reduce the memory consumption, slightly increase the bootstrap time (which is particularly useful in the serverless environments), it won't work in combination with many popular libraries commonly used in the ecosystem. For instance, if you try to build NestJS (or just express) application with MongoDB, you will see the following error in your console:
>
> Error: Cannot find module './drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection' at webpackEmptyContext
>
> Why? Because mongoose depends on mongodb which depends on kerberos (C++) and node-gyp.

Well, about `mongo`, you can make some exceptions (leave some modules in `node_modules`), can you? It's not like it's all or nothing. But still, I'm not sure you want to follow this path. I've just succeeded with bundling a `nestjs` application. It was a proof of concept, I'm not sure if it'll go into production. And it was hard, I might have broken something in the process, but at first glance it works. The most complex part was [`adminjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/adminjs). It has `rollup` and `babel` as dependencies. And in the app code they unconditionally call [`watch`](https://adminjs.co/AdminJS.html#watch) for some reason (**UDP** noop in production). Anyways, if you'd like to follow this path you should be ready to debug/inspect your packages' code. And you might need to add workarounds as new packages are added to the project. But it all depends on your dependencies, it may be easier than in my case. For a freshly created [`nestjs` + `mysql` app](https://github.com/x-yuri/nestjs-mysql-webpack) it was relatively simple.

The config I ended up with (it overrides the [`nestjs` defaults](https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/blob/v7.0.1/lib/compiler/defaults/webpack-defaults.ts#L17-L87)):

`webpack.config.js` (`webpack-5.58.2`, `@nestjs/cli-8.1.4`):

```js
const path = require('path');
const MakeOptionalPlugin = require('./make-optional-plugin');
module.exports = (defaultOptions, webpack) => {
    return {
        externals: {},  // make it not exclude `node_modules`
                        // https://github.com/nestjs/nest-cli/blob/v7.0.1/lib/compiler/defaults/webpack-defaults.ts#L24
        resolve: {
            ...defaultOptions.resolve,
            extensions: [...defaultOptions.resolve.extensions, '.json'], // some packages require json files
                                                                         // https://unpkg.com/browse/babel-plugin-polyfill-corejs3@0.4.0/core-js-compat/data.js
                                                                         // https://unpkg.com/browse/core-js-compat@3.19.1/data.json
            alias: {
                // an issue with rollup plugins
                // https://github.com/webpack/enhanced-resolve/issues/319
                '@rollup/plugin-json': '/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-json/dist/index.js',
                '@rollup/plugin-replace': '/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-replace/dist/rollup-plugin-replace.cjs.js',
                '@rollup/plugin-commonjs': '/app/node_modules/@rollup/plugin-commonjs/dist/index.js',
            },
        },
        module: {
            ...defaultOptions.module,
            rules: [
                ...defaultOptions.module.rules,

                // a context dependency
                // https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript/blob/v2.1.1/src/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.ts#L51
                {test: path.resolve('node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/sequelize/sequelize/sequelize-service.js'),
                use: [
                    {loader: path.resolve('rewrite-require-loader.js'),
                    options: {
                        search: 'fullPath',
                        context: {
                            directory: path.resolve('src'),
                            useSubdirectories: true,
                            regExp: '/\\.entity\\.ts$/',
                            transform: ".replace('/app/src', '.').replace(/$/, '.ts')",
                        },
                    }},
                ]},

                // adminjs resolves some files using stack (relative to the requiring module)
                // and actually it needs them in the filesystem at runtime
                // so you need to leave node_modules/@adminjs/upload
                // I failed to find a workaround
                // it bundles them to `$prj_root/.adminjs` using `rollup`, probably on production too
                // https://github.com/SoftwareBrothers/adminjs-upload/blob/v2.0.1/src/features/upload-file/upload-file.feature.ts#L92-L100
                {test: path.resolve('node_modules/@adminjs/upload/build/features/upload-file/upload-file.feature.js'),
                use: [
                    {loader: path.resolve('rewrite-code-loader.js'),
                    options: {
                        replacements: [
                            {search: /adminjs_1\.default\.bundle\('\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/src\/features\/upload-file\/components\/edit'\)/,
                            replace: "adminjs_1.default.bundle('/app/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/edit')"},

                            {search: /adminjs_1\.default\.bundle\('\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/src\/features\/upload-file\/components\/list'\)/,
                            replace: "adminjs_1.default.bundle('/app/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/list')"},

                            {search: /adminjs_1\.default\.bundle\('\.\.\/\.\.\/\.\.\/src\/features\/upload-file\/components\/show'\)/,
                            replace: "adminjs_1.default.bundle('/app/node_modules/@adminjs/upload/src/features/upload-file/components/show')"},
                        ],
                    }},
                ]},

                // not sure what babel does here
                // I made it return standardizedName
                // https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.16.4/packages/babel-core/src/config/files/plugins.ts#L100
                {test: path.resolve('node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js'),
                use: [
                    {loader: path.resolve('rewrite-code-loader.js'),
                    options: {
                        replacements: [
                            {search: /const standardizedName = [^;]+;/,
                            replace: match => `${match} return standardizedName;`},
                        ],
                    }},
                ]},

                // a context dependency
                // https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/v7.16.4/packages/babel-core/src/config/files/module-types.ts#L51
                {test: path.resolve('node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js'),
                use: [
                    {loader: path.resolve('rewrite-require-loader.js'),
                    options: {
                        search: 'filepath',
                        context: {
                            directory: path.resolve('node_modules/@babel'),
                            useSubdirectories: true,
                            regExp: '/(preset-env\\/lib\\/index\\.js|preset-react\\/lib\\/index\\.js|preset-typescript\\/lib\\/index\\.js)$/',
                            transform: ".replace('./node_modules/@babel', '.')",
                        },
                    }},
                ]},
            ],
        },
        plugins: [
            ...defaultOptions.plugins,
            // some optional dependencies, like this:
            // https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/core/nest-application.ts#L45-L52
            // `webpack` detects optional dependencies when they are in try/catch
            // https://github.com/webpack/webpack/blob/main/lib/dependencies/CommonJsImportsParserPlugin.js#L152
            new MakeOptionalPlugin([
                '@nestjs/websockets/socket-module',
                '@nestjs/microservices/microservices-module',
                'class-transformer/storage',
                'fastify-swagger',
                'pg-native',
            ]),
        ],

        // to have have module names in the bundle, not some numbers
        // although numbers are sometimes useful
        // not really needed
        optimization: {
            moduleIds: 'named',
        }
    };
};
```

`make-optional-plugin.js`:

```js
class MakeOptionalPlugin {
    constructor(deps) {
        this.deps = deps;
    }

    apply(compiler) {
        compiler.hooks.compilation.tap('HelloCompilationPlugin', compilation => {
            compilation.hooks.succeedModule.tap(
                'MakeOptionalPlugin', (module) => {
                    module.dependencies.forEach(d => {
                        this.deps.forEach(d2 => {
                            if (d.request == d2)
                                d.optional = true;
                        });
                    });
                }
            );
        });
    }
}

module.exports = MakeOptionalPlugin;
```

`rewrite-require-loader.js`:

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#escaping
function escapeRegExp(string) {
  return string.replace(/[.*+?^${}()|[\]\\]/g, '\\$&'); // $& means the whole matched string
}

function processFile(source, search, replace) {
    const re = `require\\(${escapeRegExp(search)}\\)`;
    return source.replace(
        new RegExp(re, 'g'),
        `require(${replace})`);
}

function processFileContext(source, search, context) {
    const re = `require\\(${escapeRegExp(search)}\\)`;
    const _d = JSON.stringify(context.directory);
    const _us = JSON.stringify(context.useSubdirectories);
    const _re = context.regExp;
    const _t = context.transform || '';
    const r = source.replace(
        new RegExp(re, 'g'),
        match => `require.context(${_d}, ${_us}, ${_re})(${search}${_t})`);
    return r;
}

module.exports = function(source) {
    const options = this.getOptions();
    return options.context
        ? processFileContext(source, options.search, options.context)
        : processFile(source, options.search, options.replace);
};
```

`rewrite-code-loader.js`:

```js
function processFile(source, search, replace) {
    return source.replace(search, replace);
}

module.exports = function(source) {
    const options = this.getOptions();
    return options.replacements.reduce(
        (prv, cur) => {
            return prv.replace(cur.search, cur.replace);
        },
        source);
};
```

The supposed way to build the app is:

```
$ nest build --webpack
```

I didn't bother with source maps, since the target is `nodejs`.

It's not a config you can just copy-paste, you should figure out what's needed for your project yourself.

One more trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70077776/52499), but well, you probably won't need it.

**UPD** `adminjs` seems to come with prebuilt bundles, so this config may be significantly simpler.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone interested, [ncc](https://github.com/vercel/ncc) does a great job for bundling a complete NestJs app into a single js file:

`ncc build src/main.ts --out dist/main.js`

No further config needed for me, although you may need to fix some of your `import` paths. It does tree shaking and even detects bindings and copies them in separate folders too.

Comment: still an awesome valid solution for building a node + typeorm app 7 years later

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Aritz I used the following variant which seems to work:

```
npm i -g @vercel/ncc
npm install -g pkg
ncc build src/main.ts --out dist/ncc-main.js
pkg dist/ncc-main.js/index.js -o myapp -t latest-linux-x64
```